# Infinite Geometric Series and its Value

Tags: real-analysis

Calculate the value of  $\sum_1^\infty (\frac{1}{3})^{2n}$.

I can clearly see that after listing a few partial sums this seems to tend toward $\frac{1}{8}$ and each partial sum is greater than the last.

$\sum_1^2 (\frac{1}{3})^{2n} = \frac{10}{81}$

$\sum_1^3 (\frac{1}{3})^{2n} = \frac{91}{729}$

$\sum_1^4 (\frac{1}{3})^{2n} = \frac{820}{6561}$

$ \frac{10}{81} \lt \frac{91}{729} \lt \frac{820}{6561} \lt {...}\lt \frac{1}{8} $

My question is how do I show that the answer is indeed $\frac{1}{8}$? I considered using a theorem in my book that says that $\sum_1^\infty x_n=\lim(s_k) = sup\{s_k :k \in N\}$ where $s_k$ are partial sums. The issue I am coming into is showing that $\frac{1}{8}$ is indeed the supremum. Any ideas would be appreciated. I also don't have to use this theorem, it was just a thought.

Comment: There is a standard formula for the sum of a geometric series, are you allowed to use this?

Comment: *Hint:*  $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{3} \right)^{2n} = \frac{1}{9} \sum_{m = 0}^{\infty} \left( \frac{1}{9} \right)^{m}$.

Comment: I was allowed to use it. I was just being dumb and really over thinking something so simple. It would be interesting to see why 1/8 is the supremum of this sequence though. I tried a proof by induction but it became far to difficult.

Answer (score 3):

The formula for the sum of a geometric series is $\dfrac{a}{1-r}$ where $a$ is the first term in the series and $r$ is the ratio you're multiplying by.

Here, $a = (\dfrac{1}{3})^{2\times1} = \dfrac{1}{9}$, and $r = \dfrac{1}{9}$.

So, we have $\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{9}}{1-\frac{1}{9}} = \dfrac{1}{9-1} = \dfrac{1}{8}$.

Comment: I haven't the slightest idea why I didn't just do that. I was really over thinking it. Thank You.

Comment: @Nid We all over-think things sometimes. You're very welcome. :)